# How to identify the state of an iOS App while crash occurs

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access, crash-log, kern-invalid-address

**With following crash log stack. Can I say that App was in Foreground state when crash occurred. because I can see `UIKit` calls.**. **What should one look to identified various state of App. like `Suspended` / `Background` / `Foreground`**

**

```
#0
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x00000000f158936c
```

**

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x3a72c626 objc_msgSend + 5
1  CoreFoundation                 0x2feae16b +[__NSArrayI __new:::] + 58
2  CoreFoundation                 0x2feab945 -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:] + 172
3  CoreFoundation                 0x2feb5341 +[NSArray arrayWithObjects:count:] + 44
4  CoreFoundation                 0x2feeb1bb -[NSDictionary allKeys] + 174
5  UIKit                          0x3292430f -[UITouchesEvent _cloneEvent] + 342
6  UIKit                          0x32786df9 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 5240
7  CoreFoundation                 0x2ff3d255 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
8  CoreFoundation                 0x2ff3abf9 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 284
9  CoreFoundation                 0x2ff3af3b __CFRunLoopRun + 730
10 CoreFoundation                 0x2fea5ebf CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
11 CoreFoundation                 0x2fea5ca3 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
12 GraphicsServices               0x34dab663 GSEventRunModal + 138
13 UIKit                          0x327f214d UIApplicationMain + 1136
14 MyApp                          0xff6bf main (main.m:16)
15 libdyld.dylib                  0x3ac2fab7 start + 2
```

Comment: As your crash said `Crashed: com.apple.main-thread` so its in foreground.

Answer (score 1):

`com.apple.main-thread` is the main thread which loads up the UI of the ViewController.
Since the crash is on the main thread then the app is to be running in foreground. 
I hope it helps.